# Warp speed collision

Tags: spaceships, faster-than-light

I was hoping that i can get a more or less science based answer because theoretically warp drive is possible (but we cannot produce the amount of energy that it needs). I am here after this question was blocked on SpaceSE.

What happens if we have two spaceships that are travelling in wrap speed and collide head-on? According to the warp theory each of the spaceships are in their own "space bubble" and are actually not moving in there but their bubble is. Each of the bubbles is contracting the space in front of it and expanding the space behind it.

So if two bubble should meet what happens? Would the bubbles contract and crash the spaceships inside them? would the bubbles just break let the ships released travelling through (normal)space in FTL speed? Is the space inside a bubble behaving like normal space and the bubbles would contract and expand each other as they pass through each other? Maybe the universe reboots?

Thank you for your time reading this.

Comment: This is a perfect example of artistic freedom. When two FTL ships come within each other's exclusion zone what happens is exactly what the story needs to happen.

Comment: Most likely there's math that's been done on this.  Have you checked whether Miguel Alcubierre has published anything ordinary folks would understand on this?

Comment: what i would do is, since its a bubble, and since the spaceships aren't technically moving, as soon as the bubble's touch which could be as large in diameter as you'd like, the bubbles would pop and speed would halt to a zero, thus meaning that the spaceships see eachother. maybe this bubble could be popped by physical objects as well so they don't fucking running into a planet and destroying it as if it was nothing.

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/   here is a more relatable analogy of what would happen.

Comment: It's a tough question since we really have no idea how to make a warp drive. The Alcubiere warp drive has a very thin region of grotesquely strong tidal forces, such that anything that passed through would be ripped apart at the sub-proton level. Maybe the two ships spray ultra-fine dust in every direction.

Comment: For ordinary bubble-benders, the drivers can pull out of traffic into a safe space, stop, and exchange insurance information. However, head-on will certainly get the Galactic Patrol involved, they will shut down the entire bypass, and I will be very late for work.